# How to Starting new Fragment from ArrayAdapter List?

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, adapter

I have a problem with my code, I don't know how to do this. Below I describe my code

Give me example how to open new fragment with ArrayAdapter List

ConfigFragment.java

public class ConfigFragment extends Fragment {

```
ListViewAdapter list;
String ConfigMenu[] = {
        "Interfaces",
        "IP Address",
        "Routes",
        "Queues",
        "Log",
        "Reboot"
};
Integer ConfigIcon[] = {
        R.drawable.ic_interface,
        R.drawable.ic_ppp,
        R.drawable.ic_routing,
        R.drawable.ic_queue,
        R.drawable.ic_log,
        R.drawable.ic_reboot
};

public ConfigFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_config, container, false);

    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), ConfigIcon, ConfigMenu);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_fragment_config);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String PilihMenu = ConfigMenu[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), PilihMenu, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I have several fragments, but I don't know how to open these fragments through ArrayAdapter

This is my several Fragment.

Interfaces.java, IP.java, Routes.java, Queues.java, Log.java

I need your help. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You open fragment by doing a transaction,
read this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments if you are new
learn some basic before jumping

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String PilihMenu = ConfigMenu[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), PilihMenu, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           //  You do your transaction here


    }
});
```